# Get Active Directory users by a list of guid

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using the UserPrincipal class in c#.  I have a list of active directory guids.

How would i get the list of DirectoryEntries using this list?

I know how to do this using one guid but not for many guids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate over your list of Guids, and fetch each user:

```
public List<UserPrincipal> FindAllUsers(List<Guid> allGuids)
{
   List<UserPrincipal> result = new List<UserPrincipal>();

   // set up domain context
   using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
   {
       foreach(Guid userGuid in allGuids)
       { 
          // find a user
          UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userGuid);

          if(user != null)
          {
              result.Add(user);
          }
       }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 Be aware that LDAP queries can be painfully slow.  Be prepared for that and consider a good caching strategy in advance.

Comment: is there any way all the guids can be passed in

Comment: @user1786107: you can pass in a **list of Guids** to your own method - but there's no way to search for a whole bunch of Guids at once in Active Directory.

Comment: @marc_s Not nessesarly, it would take more work, but if you had your class use a string builder and build a LDAP query string with `|` between the guids it could be done something like `(&(objectClass=user)(|(objectGUID=GUID_1)(objectGUID=GUID_2)(objectGUID=GUID_3)))`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain is correct.  You just need to convert the guids to a string octet. `@"\" + string.Join(@"\", guid.ToByteArray().Select(b => b.ToString("x2"))`